# creating reference for dynamic textboxes in panel

Tags: c#

Ok, am going to try and ask this without sounding dumb. I have a user form that I create dynamic textboxes inside a panel. I want to reference these textboxes or the panel from another form to send the texbox data to excel. I need to know how I can reference these controls. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Thank u Grant...I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Create public properties on the user control, one for each element you want to access.

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return textBoxName.Text; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return textBoxAddress.Text; }
    }

    ...
```

Then use those from the parent control that hosts the user control.

```
string name = myControl1.Name;
string address = myControl.Address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `Form1` that dynamically adds a `TextBox` to panel `panel1` during the load event like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
}
```

And you have `Form2` from which you want to access the data on `panel1`. On `Form2` you can add a public field to store the reference to `panel1`, but you can call it whatever you want. In this case, I use `sourcePanel`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public Panel sourcePanel;

   public Form2()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

Then you can pass the `panel1` reference to any new `Form2` instance when the new instance is created, for example from a button click event on `Form1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 f2 = new Form2();
   f2.sourcePanel = panel1;
   f2.Show();
}
```

Then on `Form2`, you can access all the values in the TextBoxes with code like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (TextBox txt in sourcePanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(txt.Text);
   }
}
```